# Watch commits made to followed GitHub repositories in the dashboard

Tags: github, news-feed

GitHub allows users to "watch" and "star" repositories. But neither of these buttons gives me an option to follow pushes to these repos that would appear in my news feed - GitHub homepage when I'm logged in.

In my newsfeed, I now only have pushes to my repositories and forks/stars of users I follow. I want to see if someone makes a commit to my favourite framework etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing pull requests and commits to repositories if you're Watching them. There are three watch states:

- **Not watching** - You only receive notifications for discussions in which you participate or are @mentioned.
- **Watching** - You receive notifications for all discussions in this repository.
- **Ignoring** - You do not receive any notifications for discussions in this repository.

Watching is the one you should be using if you want to see activity in your news feed. You don't need to fork a project for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm the original author.*

[This project](https://github.com/AurelienLourot/github-commit-watcher) allows you to get an e-mail when a commit gets pushed on a repository you are watching.

Explaination: *gicowa* is a command-line tool written in python that lists all last commits on all GitHub repos you are watching. This tool can send its output via e-mail and can be called from your `crontab`. Doing that makes you receive an e-mail notification each time a commit gets pushed on a GitHub repo you are watching (on any branch).

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how this works? What you need to do to set it up? Link only answers are generally not embraced here. If you are the author can you specify your connection explicitly? Thanks

Comment: Good point, hope it's better now.